# merge two images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge and wrap UIImage on mug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737828/merge-and-wrap-uiimage-on-mug)

i have two image and i want to merge those two images like i have a image of mug and second image is any image now i want to merge with it to mug how could i achieve this [image]

now suppose cup is totally white and than i merge the other image with on it how should i achieve this ????

Comment: Do you just want to display both images one on top of the other onscreen? Or do you want to generate a new binary file containing the overlay?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could make a custom `UIView` and override the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`
 and write something like this:

```
CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.img1 drawInRect:self.bounds blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];
[self.img2 drawInRect:self.bounds blendMode:kCGBlendModeDarken alpha:1];
```

img1 is a `UIImage` containing the mug image and img2 is another  `UIImage` containing the overlay.

Also, check out the other blend modes supported by iOS. (`kCGBlendModeDarken` compares each pixel from img1 and img2 and selects the darkest one). For a much better explanation of blendmodes, then the one offered by apple, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes

Comment: will u please explain more or link some tutorial

Comment: This tutorial is pretty good http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1681

Comment: will you please give me source code link for testing?